# Quick question to proof of bijection in measure

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Hi am am taking a course in measure- and integral theory. Here I have been asked to prove that there exists a bijection $ f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.
Would it suffice to find a function that is a bijection and prove injectivity and surjectivity or would this be not be the point of such an exercise?

Function found:

$ g(x)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right) $

$ g^{-1}(x)=\frac {1}{1+e^x} $

Comment: Your idea is right, but your example doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, notice that $[0,1]$ is a **closed** interval, so you can't really expect to create a *continuous* bijective function between it and $\mathbb R$. There exist bijections between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$, however, and it isn't hard to produce a discontinuous bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Second of all, your function most certainly is not a bijection, since $g(x)>0$ for all values of $x$. In fact, your function maps $[0,1]$ to $[\frac{1}{1+e}, \frac12]$.

Comment: That makes sense, hadn't really noticed that obviously. I do think i made a small mistake in the post, switched the function and inverse, look at edit.
But even with the edit the is a problem because it is the closed interval. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @comjens Now, your function isn't even *defined* for $x\in\{0,1\}$, so it is not even a function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$

Comment: I see that too, I am too hasty sorry.